# Give a percentage(5%) to randomly permute values of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am still new to Numpy and Python. I would like to know what's the more efficient way to randomly change the order for only 5% of the values in a numpy array and keep the same index order for the other 95% values left ?

Let's say I have the following array with 100 integers elements.

```
In [7]:a

Out[8]:   array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,
    2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
    2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
    1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,
    0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  1.,
    2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
    1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,
    1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.])
```

How can I randomly permute the order of 5% of the values using python and numpy ?

Comment: So you want to shuffle a random 5%?

Comment: What's the meaning of the input?

Comment: yes @James. Basically, I want to permute/shuffle a random 5%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a 5% sample of the index, create a copy of the values at those indices, shuffle the values, then reassign.  Keep in mind that `np.random.shuffle` is an in-place operation.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
  [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,
    2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
    2.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,
    1.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,
    0.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  2.,  1.,
    2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,
    1.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,
    1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  2.,  2.,  1.])
ix_size = int(0.05 * len(a))
ix = np.random.choice(len(a), size=ix_size, replace=False)
b = a[ix]
np.random.shuffle(b)
a[ix] = b
```

Comment: No need to construct `np.arange`, I think.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: @James the first argument to `np.random.choice` can as well be an `int` if all you want is an array of indices

Comment: @Eli-Korvigo, thanks!  I had not seen that feature before.

Comment: Since you've been a tad faster than me, I'm going to remove my answer. I would only recommend you to replace those variable names with something more readable and sensible, especially since the OP is a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np


array = ...
# how many positions to permute
nsamples = int(round(len(array)*0.05))
# select random positions
positions = np.random.choice(len(array), nsamples, replace=False)
# extract values at selected positions
sample = array[positions]
# shuffle the sample
np.random.shuffle(sample)
# apply changes to the original array
array[positions] = sample
```

Comment: `sample = array[positions]` would already make a copy, since it's an [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) operation. You don't need to explicitly call `copy`.